# Laravel grouped collection returns object instead of array

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I have the following query

```
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
});

return response()->json([
    'outings' => $outings
], 200);
```

The response is returning an object and I need it to return an array
[image: As you can see, outings is an object and not an array]

How can I get outings to be an array instead of an object.

If I don't group the collection and just do

```
Outing::all();
```

It will return an array rather than an object. The Group by is doing something weird.

If I DD($outings) it does in fact return a collection, so I think it's odd that it gets cast to an object when returned to the browser rather than an array.

Below is the output when I DD($outings->toArray())

[image]

Thanks

Comment: just send it `return response()->json($outings, 200);`

Comment: Thanks @rkj, however that still returns an object to the browser.

Comment: Add `toArray()` to `$outings`. So it will be `$outings->toArray();`

Comment: It is worth nothing [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources).

Comment: @bak87, That was the first thing I tried, it still returns an object. Thanks

Comment: @wild-beard I am using a resource but simplified it here to make it easier to read. I Pass my query through the resource then call group by on that.

Comment: @KyleReierson Can you show us the output when you try `dd($outings->toArray())` after the grouping?

Comment: @user3574492, I have attached an image of the dd($outings->toArray()) Thanks!

Comment: @KyleReierson How are you seeing the response? Chrome dev tools?

Comment: @user3574492 Yes Chrom dev tools

Comment: @KyleReierson i have updated answer, can you try it.

Comment: I think that is because you are sending the response as Json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you want array then use this

```
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
})->map(function($item){
    return $item->all();
});

return response()->json($outings, 200);
```

> If you want date as key then

```
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
});

return response()->json($outings->toArray(), 200);
```

Comment: That will still return an array of objects

Comment: That works! However I need to keep the date as the key in the groupings. array_values resets them to 0,1,2 etc

Comment: if you keep the date as groupings then it will return you object again

Comment: @KyleReierson you either get array or if you want date as key then you must have object because associative array converted to json object.

Comment: Ah, duh. Thanks for your help! I was able to work with this and get the data in the format I need after using array_values

Answer (score 18):

Use `array_values($array)` to force an associative array into a JSON array. You will lose any key names this way, however.

```php
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
});

return response()->json([
    'outings' => array_values($outings)
], 200);
```

No one has really explained why this happens.

In JavaScript/JSON, arrays are just collections of values, they are keyed but the key is always numerical in sequence.

In PHP, arrays are collections of `"key" => "value"` pairs, the key can be anything (integer or string) but arrays can generally be considered "associative" (where the key is non-numerical, or numerical but not in sequence) or "non-associative" (where the key is numerical AND in sequence (similar to JS arrays).

When it comes to encoding a PHP array as JSON, say an array has keys that are non-numeric OR the keys are numeric but not in sequential order (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10) - these types of arrays are not compatible with JavaScript/JSON arrays. In this case, the array is converted into an object to preserve the keys. To force the array to be converted into an array, you must convert the array into a non-associative array (numerical sequenced keys), PHP has the function [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to help with this.

Comment: i like the explanation. makes a lot of sense 

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, especially this part: "OR the keys are numeric but not in sequential order"! I spent so much time trying to figure out why one set of results was returning as an array, but the other one as an object.

Answer (score 7):

Use ->values()

```php
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
});

return response()->json([
    'outings' => $outings->values()
], 200);
```

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: This works for me, thank you! In my case, my iteration of collection modifies the keys of each item - which is the cause of rendering return as object, not array. - thus **->values()** is needed for resetting keys in consecutive order. [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-values)

Answer (score 7):

On Laravel 8 using Inertia.js with Vue3, I ran into a similar issue. I was trying to return an array of objects `Array<{label, name}>`

The way I solved it was

```php
return collect($myArray)->map(function($key, $value) {
   return [
      'name' => $value,
      'label' => $key
    ];
   })->values(); // <---- this guy
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick for me! Had a Collection with Collections inside. Needed a return value of Collection as well. Using `->values()` did exactly what I needed. When using `->toArray()` as suggested in other answers, the return value becomes an array instead of a Collection.

Answer (score 1):

**on laravel 8**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all()->toArray();
        return array_reverse($products);      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
});

return response()->json([
    'outings' => $outings->toArray()
], 200);
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, still returns an object

Comment: @KyleReierson Can you show us the output when you try `dd($outings->toArray())` after the grouping?

Answer (score 0):

```
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
})->toArray();

return response()->json([
    'outings' => $outings
], 200);
```

Have a look at [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray)

Also Try

```
$outings = Outing::all()->groupBy(function ($item) {
   return Carbon::parse($item['start'])->format('m/d/Y');
})->toArray();

return response()->json([
    'outings' => json_encode($outings)
], 200);
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, still returns an object

Comment: @KyleReierson try ```(\Arrayable) $outings``` see what happens

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to go from a collection of objects to an array of arrays, the sneaky way to do it is json encode/decode. That'll turn any object in there to an array. So if you do something like:

```
$my_collection = People::get(['id', 'name']);
$my_array = json_decode(json_encode($my_collection), true);
```

You'll go from:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection { 
  App\Models\People{id: 123, name: "steve"}, 
  App\Models\People{id: 456, name: "sara"},
  ...
}
```

to:

```
[ 
  ["id" => 123, "name" => "steve"], 
  ["id" => 456, "name" => "sara"],
  ...
]
```