# How to delete data using Vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying delete data but I'm getting this error:

```
this.jobPosts.filter is not a function
```

PostJobIndex.vue file:

```
deleteJobPost: async function(jobPost) {
                if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Job Post?')) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    await employerService.deleteJobPost(jobPost.id);

                    this.jobPosts = this.jobPosts.filter(obj => {
                        return obj.id != jobPost.id;
                    });

                    console.log(this.jobPosts);

                    this.$toast.success("Job Post deleted Successfully!");
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                }
            },
```

I had this same issue with my Update method and I beleive it was because I was trying to map through an object or something instead of an array. In the end I used `Object.keys(this.jobPosts).map` for my update method and it worked:

```
Object.keys(this.jobPosts).map(jobPost => {
                        if (jobPost.id == response.data.id) {
                            for (let key in response.data) {
                                jobPost[key] = response.data[key];
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

But when I do this for Update it doesn't work:

```
this.jobPosts = Object.keys(this.jobPosts).filter(obj => {
                        return obj.id != jobPost.id;
                    });
```

UPDATED

Here is the code for loading the job posts:

```
loadJobPosts: async function() {
                try {
                    const response = await employerService.loadJobPosts();
                    this.jobPosts = response.data;

                    console.log(this.jobPosts);

                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error('Some error occurred, please refresh!');
                }
            },
```

Im using Vuex for state management and I'm using services, that simply contain the axios http requests. That's where this line comes from `employerService.loadJobPosts()` `loadJobPosts()` is a function inside my employerService.js file.

I'm also using Laravel for my back end. Here is my JobPostsController.php file:

```
public function index()
    {
        $jobPosts = JobPost::all()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

        return response()->json($jobPosts, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Is jobPosts an array? Can you confirm that? Most of the times, this error occurs when you try to apply filter on a not array type.

Comment: in my data() object, I have this jobPosts: [], but in the console it says Object. I don't know how to return the data as an array.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could edit your answer to include the code where you assign data to `this.jobPosts`

Comment: Okay, I added my ```loadJobPosts()``` function and some more details in my post under UPDATED.

Comment: Not sure if your _employerService_ already parses the JSON string. After that just process your parsed object with Object.values(this.jobPosts) to get your array.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood from your code,

this should work for removing `jobPost` from `jobPosts`

```
this.jobPosts = this.jobPosts.filter(obj => {
    return obj.id != jobPost.id;
});
```

I don't know what you're expecting this to do, but it **won't** do anything useful and will either error or return false for everything.

```
this.jobPosts = Object.keys(this.jobPosts).filter(obj => {
    return obj.id != jobPost.id;
});
```

`filter` exists on array types, so I would check where it's getting set and make sure it's an array.

I've included a small snippet in case it's any help.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      jobPosts: [],
      deleteJobId: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getJobPosts() {
      this.jobPosts = [{
        id: 1
      }, {
        id: 2
      }, {
        id: 3
      }, {
        id: 4
      }, {
        id: 5
      }];

    },
    deleteJob() {
      if (!this.deleteJobId)
        return;

      this.jobPosts = this.jobPosts.filter(x => x.id !== this.deleteJobId);
    }

  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="getJobPosts">Get Jobs</button>

  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="deleteJob">Delete Job #</button>
    <input type="number" v-model.number="deleteJobId" />

  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="jobPost in jobPosts">
      Job Post #{{jobPost.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is an object, which is why it's not working. Do you know how to convert an Object or a set of Objects into an array using Javascript?

Comment: Strange, I did this:
```
this.jobPosts = Object.values(this.jobPosts).filter(obj => {
                        return obj.id != jobPost.id;
                    });
```
and it deleted from the page, But not from the database.

Comment: If your `console.log(this.jobPosts);` returns an object and not an array then sorry I can't help as I don't know Laravel. Your Object.values code probably looked like it worked but actually returned false for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own question:

> in my data() object, I have this jobPosts: [], but in the console it says Object

As for your second question:

> I don't know how to return the data as an array

There are [similiar topics here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087064/laravel-grouped-collection-returns-object-instead-of-array).
I am not familiar with Laravel but assuming you have an eloquent model with JobPost in your index-function according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-toarray) you should use the .toArray-method:

```
$jobPosts = JobPost::all()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id).toArray();
```

When working with plain collections the values method should do the trick of returning an array instead of an object:

```
$collection = collect([
  10 => ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
  11 => ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200]
]);

$values = $collection->values();

$values->all();
```

**UPDATE**

I just realized that your result is just a stringified JSON object that needs to be converted into an array. Just parse it before processing (take out the JSON.parse(...) if you are already taking care of it in your service), return the object properties as an array and you are good to go:)

```
this.jobPosts = Object.values(JSON.parse(this.jobPosts)).filter(obj => {
  return obj.id != jobPost.id;
});
```

Comment: For some reason the ```->toArray()``` is still returning an Object. And for me ```$jobPosts->values()``` returns an error.