# Laravel returning data as object instead of array

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$arr = [];

$arr['into']['box'] = 1;

return $arr;
```

But it returns this:

```
{
  "into": {
    "box": 1
  }
}
```

As you can see it should be array, not object!!

I searched a lot but I didn't find anything.

Help me and give me the code or the tip please.

Comment: your `$arr` is multidimentional array, it uses named keys. That's why. What output do you expect?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087064/laravel-grouped-collection-returns-object-instead-of-array

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#creating-responses):

> In addition to returning strings from your routes and controllers, you may also return arrays. The framework will automatically convert the array into a JSON response:

The same is true for models, and collections:

> Did you know you can also return Eloquent collections from your routes or controllers? They will automatically be converted to JSON. Give it a shot!

Comment: Thanks @dont-panic for your reply. I cant do it also in pure PHP, is there any way?!

Comment: @Gambleguy [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script) of manually doing what Laravel is doing automatically behind the scenes, if that's what you mean.